# Can GraphQL break SQL Server when attempting queries with 1 to very high number JOINs? What issues can arise from such JOINs?

Tags: sql-server, performance, graphql

Our code development team is implementing a GraphQL API to replace the current method for our website to access the AWS RDS Web Edition SQL Server 2017 back-end.
I have noticed that a query across multiple tables does not use the DB native relations, but loads each table individually and passes filtered parameters of the rows required for each table, derived from the previous table keys.

Example of TSQL query:

```
Select c.Name
from a
inner join b on b.b_id = a.b_id
inner join c on c.c_id = b.c_id
```

Similar generated through GraphQL. Bit pseudo-codish because it is GraphQL holding the rseults of the SELECTs:

```
Select a.b_id [into a table within GraphQL API. Let's call it *b_ids*] 
from a

Select b.c_id [again into a GraphQL table *c_ids*]
from b
where b.id IN([list of ids in *b_ids*])

Select c.Name
from c
WHERE c.id IN ([list of ids in *c_ids*])
```

All we see on a trace is:

```
Select a.b_id 
from a

Select b.c_id
from b
where b.id IN(1, 2, 3, 4 etc..)

Select c.Name
from c
WHERE c.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4 etc..)
```

I am concerned about this method, the performance that may suffer and the threshold of SQL Server queries (64KB) that may be breached on 1 to very many rows in cascades. We have junction tables with hundreds of thousands of rows.

I would have thought if my concerns were valid then there would be much to find online, but I haven't found anything. Has anyone used these platforms together that can give some indications, warnings or reassurance, particularly in regard to using with a website requiring quick responses. Tips appreciated.

Comment: What does `into b_ids` and `list of b_ids` mean here? Are they dumping the values into a temp table and `select`ing back out, or are they taking the values back to client and sending them back again as parameters? Both are bad, in different ways

Comment: This looks to me very similar to performance and scalability issues I've seen with developers using ORM tools such as EF or nhibernate. You're using a tool to write your data access logic for you - sometimes this is fine and the benefit is the developer can create crud operations quickly and benefit from version control; the downside is that often you end up with massively underperforming database access, usually with the developer being completely oblivious to what is actually going on - fortunately it looks like at least not in your case.

Comment: @Charlieface Traces only show the statements with hard-coded IN() values. GraphQL holds the values outside of SQL Server and puts them into the statements it passes.

Comment: Well let's have a minimal real statement, the code you gave us is clearly not real code. Yes, this type of code is going to be really slow, I suggest you find a way to do proper joins

Comment: @Stu We have used EFs that are much better than this. At least they can use relations SQL Server side with JOINs. GraphQL loads the necessary data from the tables with individual statements. Ideally, someone with GraphQL experience could say if it is a suitable method for a popular retail website to access its product data.

Comment: @Charlieface due to much of the processing being done in the API tier, the SQL code won't make much sense; hence the pseudocode, but I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Are you aware of DataLoader pattern/concept, popular in graphQL world?

Comment: @xadm Is it the DataLoader part that is generating the giant IN() clauses as a workaround to N+1 issues? It looks as if we are using the DataLoader and that is the issue. However, the alternative N+1 issue is unacceptable, also.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about GraphQL, but queries with large `IN` lists can be expensive to parse and compile and will not scale to arbitrary-sized data.  However, [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) on the size of a TSQL query is ~65MB not 64KB, and performance should become an issue well before you hit that limit.

As a more-scalable alternative, pass the data using Table-Valued Parameters, a JSON array, or bulk load a temporary table.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my understanding of query size. I have recommended passing values to a user-def table type, but this does not make use of the GraphQL features for which they chose the tool.